# how to add facebook like button in my UIView based iphone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am new in objective c. I need to add facebook like button in my UIView based application. For this case i have create a action button and write bellow code:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,  0.0, 320.0, 460.0)];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html>\
<body style=\"color: #000000; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 10pt;\">\
<tr>\
<td colspan=2>\
<a style=\"color: #000000; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 10pt; width:50px; height:20px;\" href=https://www.facebook.com/abc..><img src=\"facebook_like.png\" width=50 height=50 style=\"float:left; \" /></a><br>\
    </td>\
</tr>\
</body>\
</html>"];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

But when i click on action button it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has not provided this in their SDK, but there is an open-source Github project called  [FacebookLikeView](https://github.com/brow/FacebookLikeView) that you can either use or inspect to see how they did it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use UIButton. I'm not exactly sure what youre trying to accomplish though.

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,  0.0, 320.0, 460.0);
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook_like.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPushed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Hopefully this can help. Don't forget to add - buttonPushed:(id)sender to that class. And for that matter, add it to your view.

Comment: I understand now. A Facebook "LIKE" button. not a Facebook-like button. Wow. Dumb moment.

Comment: Thanks , It is face book "LIKE" button. Actually i used a action like -(IBAction)facebookBtn:(id)sender{ //--- here i have used above code which i have post}  .  But it is going to the page but i did not get any back button how i can solve this issue.

Comment: I'd recommend using what @coneybeare posted. It looks to be excactly what you want.

Comment: Will you provide me the link?